# How do I install node v8 in windows while node website provides non exe files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to install old version of node (v8). When I visit node website, I see they put non-exe files for windows as you see here:
[node version 8](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.0.0/win-x64/)

**so how do I execute these files on windows 7?**

Comment: use nvmw, and switch to any version of the node after installing 
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the latest version of Node.js from the official site.

Then you can install Node Version Manager(NVM)

Please follow below steps to install NVM

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

After installing NVM you can use whichver node version you want using

`nvm install 8.0`

Answer (score 2):

You should download .msi file instead, also you can try to use chocolatey https://chocolatey.org/, it is package manager for windows. Just type `choco install nodejs` after installing chocolatey

Answer (score 0):

You can install nvm. NVM can Manage multiple installations of node.js on a Windows computer. This is very useful when u need to use multiple node versions or if need to switch the node version.

Follow the steps below to install such environment.

1) Download **nvm_setup.zip** file for window from [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)

2) extract and install nvm to your computer

**use following commands to install and configure multiple node versions**

1. **nvm install  [arch]** (ex. nvm install 4.0.0 32).
2. **nvm list** - shows which versions installed previously.
3. **nvm use**  - to switch the nodejs versions if multiple versions are present.

For better understanding you can [visit here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Install node, then use the following command to install the previous versions (where x.y.z is the version you wish to downgrade to.)

```
npm install -g node@x.y.z
```